# Invalid redirect when using Auth.js (v5) with Docker in Next.JS

Tags: typescript, docker, next.js, next-auth, t3

Did anyone successfully implement the latest Auth.js version in production with Docker? I am using the t3-stack (tRPC, Auth.JS, Prisma, Next.JS).

I have tried to upgrade to the beta version with the Prisma Adapter, but when using any provider to sign in it basically redirects to the Docker internal host which is `0.0.0.0.` I don't know if this is some kind of issue within Auth.js itself or Next.JS.

So basically setting the `NEXTAUTH_URL` and/or `AUTH_URL` environment variable to the production url at least sets the correct redirect url on the provider page, but after a successful sign in you still get redirected to `0.0.0.0`.

(My application and the auth flow was working prior to upgrading to Auth.js)

In my Dockerfile I have set the following according to the official Next.JS documentation:

```
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"
```

My Auth.js configuration looks like this:

```
export const {
  handlers: { GET, POST },
  auth,
} = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
    signOut: "/auth/logout",
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request",
  },
  callbacks: {
    signIn({ user, email }) {
      // If email provider is used, only allow users with a specific email domain
      if (email?.verificationRequest) {
        return !isFakeEmail(user.email!, false);
      }

      return true;
    },
    session: ({ session, user }) => ({
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        id: user.id,
        role: user.role,
        subscribedTill: user.subscribedTill,
      },
    }),
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: env.EMAIL_FROM,
      maxAge: 5 * 60, // valid for 5 minutes
    }),
    DiscordProvider({ allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true }),
    GitHubProvider({ allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true }),
  ],
  trustHost: true, // Notice trustHost being set to true
});
```

In my .env file I already tried various combinations of emitting **NEXTAUTH_URL** / **AUTH_URL** or using both together.

Currently using `AUTH_URL="https://my-production-url.com/api/auth"` achieves the above described behaviour (correct oauth redirect path, wrong redirect on successful oauth sign in).

I am also using the following package versions:

```
"@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.15",
"next": "14.1.0",
```

Maybe I am missing some kind of variable? I found this related discussion on GitHub, but without any real solution: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/8449